# Is the following conditional density function equivalent to its unconditional counterpart?

Tags: probability, density-function, stochastic-processes, conditional-independence

Suppose we have a stochastic series $\{X_t\in\mathbb{R}, t=1,\cdots, T\}$. Further suppose that $G(X_t)=\mathbf{1}_{X_t\geq 0}$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is an indicator function. Can it be concluded that the conditional density

\begin{equation}
f_{X_t\mid G(X_t)}(x_t) = f_{X_t}(x_t)
\end{equation}

I think not, as the function alone suggests dependence between $X_t$ and $G(X_t)$. If that is not the case, assuming that $X_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ for all $t$, how can we express/ evaluate the conditional density function on the left hand side of the above equation?

Comment: For additional answers, please search our site for posts about [densities of truncated distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=condition*%20trunc*%20density&searchOn=3).